# Intuition behind cellular automaton mixed bulking function?

Tags: cellular-automata

I'm reading the paper of Nicolas Ollinger on intrisically universal 1d cellular automata: https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.3213.

On page 3 (201), he gave the definition for mixed bulking quasi order. I'm unable to grasp the intuition behind such a defintion, injective universality seems to already capture what I can imagine universality to be. Another issue is that the mixed bulking map $\phi$ has domain $2^{S_B}$, how is $\phi$ composed with the global function $G_B$ when $G_B$ has domain $S_B^{Z^d}$？